# posting form and retieving posted data in another page using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to post a form to another php page. The posted data is processed in the php page and page needs to be redirected to a new url.

1) Where do i give this code for posting the data to test.php. Do i have to call this in a function when the submit button is clicked?

```
 $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

2) How do i retrieve the posted data in the test.php?

Thanks
Prady

Comment: do you want to pass url from js to test.php or test.php to js

Comment: sorry if my question was a bit confusing... i have a page called form.htm where i accept a few form values. I want to pass these values to test.php and when the processing of data is doneon test.php i need to redirect to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is working example**

```
<script>
  var data="google";
  $.post(  
      'test.php',  
      { data: data},  
      function(response){  
        if(response.status=='success')
        window.location.href = response.url;
        else
        alert('url not retrive');
      }  
  ,json);    
</script>
```

**test.php**

```
  if($data="google")
  {
   $return = array('status'=>'success','url' => 'http://google.com');
   echo json_encode($return);
  }
?>
```

Comment: one last question... Do i need to call this script function explicitly on for the submit button or does the click of submit button runs this script?

Comment: right now it run default but you can implement this script with click and submit both.